# Why can't I play the Xbox Live Arcade games I've bought without an internet connection?

Tags: xbox-live-arcade, xbox-360

A long time ago, I bought a few games from Xbox Live Arcade (Toy Soldiers and Greed Corporation). We haven't set up our internet connection yet since we moved, but I can still play them unlocked.

The youngest also enjoys these games so we decided to get them on his Xbox. We went to a friends place, used the friend's Xbox which was connected to the internet and bought the games on our silver account.

As long as the youngest's Xbox is connected to the internet, the games are full games and unlocked, but once I take it back home and set it up off the internet, the games revert back to trial games.

Is there anyway to unlock these games on his Xbox like they are on my Xbox?

I heard it might be related to the fact that originally, the silver account was on a memory card, but i transfered it to the hard drive a few months ago.

Comment: can you confirm what 'Anna Lear' commented on below? Were the games purchased on the same console that you are having troubles with getting the games to be recognized on when there is no internet connection? If that's the case, can you check https://live.xbox.com/en-US/ConsoleLicenseTransfer/Begin to see that those items are licensed to that console correctly? You don't have to start the process, but it should tell you what has been licensed to that console there.

Comment: also, which console was the Silver account created on?

Comment: Having the same issue with fruit ninja , moved the hard drive to a new machine ,it reverted back to a trial edition , going to attempt to move the hard drive back to the old 360 and see if it corrects the process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you purchase a game from XBLA, that game is licensed in 2 ways:

1. To the account you purchase with it.
2. To the machine that you purchase it on.

Seeing as you purchased those games on another machine, that's why it is requiring you to be online to verify those games are licensed to your account.

What you need to do is transfer content licenses to your console. It is a multi-step process, and you need to be with your new machine as you might need the Console ID, but it's fairly painless and quick. The full instructions and some videos for the license transfer are found at [www.xbox.com/drm](http://www.xbox.com/drm).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but I think the youngest son has his own xbox and they brought it to their friend's house to bring it online.

Comment: @Anna Lear you might be right, guess I was confused with the references to his xbox and the other one.

Comment: when i activated the games, i did it on the friends console with the youngest his hard drive on it. i will give this a try.

Comment: @Andy then it sounds like this should work, the licenses should be tied to your friends console. Let us know if it works out.

Comment: where would i find this console id?

Comment: @Andy You shouldn't need the ID, if you read the instructions and watch the video at the link above it will show you what you need to do. Make sure you are logged into your son's silver account and with the console so that you can turn it on and log in to it when necessary. All that said, if you do need it, you should be able to find the Console ID under the system information tab on the dashboard, and I believe it's on the sticker on the box along with the serial number.