# My Minecraft 360 got deleted, Why?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Recently I tried to play Minecraft 360 edition with my sister, and for some reason it only gave me the trial version. Which is strange because I downloaded the game a month after it was released on the 360. I do not know what happened, and I would like to know. Can anyone tell me why this has happened? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The trial version and the full version of arcade games are actually the same thing, it's drm (digital rights management) that determines which version you have access to. When you purchase a game initially, it is made available to you on one of two conditions: You are playing it on the console you purchased it on OR you are playing using the xbox live account you purchased it with. These rights are transferable, but it is a bit of a hassle. If a different account than the one you are using originally made the purchase on a different console, than you will only have access to the trial version.

Comment: see this answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/17915/47872

Comment: @Vaishali at the time I figure it would be a duplicate question, I'm still tempted to flag it as a duplicate to answer I linked.

Answer (score 4):

The trial version and the full version of arcade games are actually the same game. It's drm (digital rights management) that determines which version you have access to. When you purchase a game initially on XBox Live, it is made available to you on one of two conditions: You are playing it on the console you purchased it on OR you are playing using the XBox Live account you purchased it with. These rights are transferable, but it is a bit of a hassle. If an account different than the one you are using had originally made the purchase on a different console, then you will only have access to the trial version.

[see this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/17915/47872)

Note, it doesn't matter what hard drive was in the machine at the time of the purchase, the rights to the game are tied to the console. If you were to try to use the hard drive on a different machine, it will show up as the trial version unless you have the XBox live account associated with the license.